# Obtain coefficients using least square method of an equation with TWO variables (multidimensional)

Tags: least-squares

How do I get the coefficient $a$ and $b$ from this equation using least square method? What is the best way to solve this?
$$
\{{a, b\}}=argmin_{\{a,b\}}\sum_{k1,k2}(\theta(k_1,k_2)−(ak_1+bk_2))^2
$$
I tried this method, but I'm not sure it's correct:

Let's say $\theta(k_1,k_2)$ is a matrix of $60 x 60$ (constant/values), but $\theta(k_1,k_2)\approx ak_1+bk_2$, thus let $C$, $A$ and $Y$ be a matrix:

$Y=$
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&.&.&.&60\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
60&.&.&.&.&.&60
\end{matrix}
$$
$A=$
$$
\begin{matrix}
a&1\\
1&b
\end{matrix}
$$
$C=$
$$
\begin{matrix}
k_1\\
k_2
\end{matrix}
$$
From here how do I solve it?
Please guide me. Thanks in advance!

Reference paper: [Here](https://mega.nz/#!vp9WFDbb!pEG8pem9n2SaX8IHxbUxnD4JT6ngp0nF608T3zAeiJY) (Section III)

Comment: You will have to explain your notation for matrices, also you cant divide matrices like that as division isn't defined for them

Comment: Edited, I hope it's clearer. Please do correct me. Thanks!